# How do I only show formula data for those rows that have input data in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Say I have a simple Excel form like this:

```
|  3 | 3 |  6 |
|  2 | 7 |  9 |
|    |   |  0 |
|    |   |  0 |
|    |   |  0 |
|    |   |  0 |
```

where the third column is a formula of the first two (in this example, SUM).
How do I only display the third column if the first have values?
In the example I simply added `=SUM(A1;B1)` to the third column and dragged it down but that will give 0 for all empty lines but I would like them to be blank.

Comment: Did you mean `A1;A2` or did you mean `A1;B1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `IF` and `ISNUMBER`

Something like

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(A1), SUM(A1:B1), "")
```

This assumes that your A and B column will either both have a value, or both will have no value.

Comment: That will show blank fields if there are input values which are 0. In that case I want to see the zero.

Comment: @CorporalTouchy, updated

Comment: I think the first if is obsolete now. Just =IF(ISNUMBER(A1), SUM(A1:B1), "") will do.

Comment: Is it possible to have this formula be valid for the entire column? Just dragging for a while seems a bit crude. ;)

Comment: The only way I know would be to do it in VBa, sorry, I don't know how

Answer (score 0):

Alternative answer:

> =IF(SUBTOTAL(3;A1:B1)>0;SUM(A1:B1);"")

SUBTOTAL(3,... is equal to COUNTA() - count the cells that has content.

So this checks whether there is at least one cell with content (might be a zero) and then sums all the cells.